# Find the tangent plane of $z=2x^2+y^2$ at the point $(1, 1, 3)$ using only vectors?

Tags: vectors, partial-derivative

I know partial derivatives should be used to solve this, but I'm wondering is there any to find the plane using the vector method of getting the Normal vector and a point on the plane. In this case, we already have a point, we just need to somehow find the Normal vector.

Also, is there any connection between Normal vectors and partial derivatives in this case of finding equations for tangent planes?

Comment: The normal vector is the gradient of $f(x, y, z)$ at the point, when you write the surface in the form $f=0$

Answer (score 0):

This question should be approached as follows.

The algebraic (implicit) equation of the given paraboloid can be expressed as

$ F(x,y,z) = 0$

where

$ F(x,y,z) = 2 x^2 + y^2 - z $

The normal to the plane is along the gradient vector of $F(x,y,z) $,

and this is given by

$ N = ( F_x, F_y, F_z) = ( 4 x, 2 y , -1 ) $

At $(x,y,z) = (1, 1, 3)$ we get

$ N = (4, 2, -1) $

So that the equation of the tangent plane is

$ 4 (x - 1) + 2 (y - 1) - (z -3) = 0 $

which gives

$ \boxed{ 4x + 2y - z - 3 = 0 } $

Comment: Thanks.  I'll correct that.

Comment: Now rewrite the sentence. It’s not the gradient vector of $F=0$.

Comment: Thanks @TedShifrin for your pointers.  I've corrected my answer again to reflect this important detail that you brought to my attention.  I think my answer should be correct now.

Comment: Well done. Correct and clear explanations are an important part of teaching.